# Format a number with SI Prefix, with fixed number of decimals

Tags: d3.js

I'm looking over the available type for d3.format

> The available type values are:
>
> exponent ("e") - use Number.toExponential.
>
> general ("g") - use Number.toPrecision.
>
> fixed ("f") - use Number.toFixed.
>
> integer ("d") - use Number.toString, but ignore any non-integer values.
>
> rounded ("r") - like fixed, but round to precision significant digits.
>
> percentage ("%") - like fixed, but multiply by 100 and suffix with "%".
>
> rounded percentage ("p") - like rounded, but multiply by 100 and suffix with "%".
>
> SI-prefix ("s") - **like rounded**, but with a unit suffixed such as "9.5M" or "1.00µ".

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format

What I would like is an SI-prefix that is like fixed not rounded does such a format option exist?

Some examples:

```
var format = d3.format('.1s');
format(12600000); // Would like 12.6M get 10M
format(12400000); // Would like 12.4M get 10M
format(1240000); // Would like 1.2M get 1M
format(1290000); // Would like 1.3M get 1M
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You almost got it right. Using [`d3.formatPrefix()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_formatPrefix) one can get the SI prefix. To get the rounded number without decimals, I used [Javascript's `.toFixed()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp):

```
var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(137594020);
console.log(prefix.symbol); // "M"
console.log(prefix.scale(137594020).toFixed()); // 138

var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(13759402);
console.log(prefix.symbol); // "M"
console.log(prefix.scale(13759402).toFixed()); // 14

var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(1375);
console.log(prefix.symbol); // "k"
console.log(prefix.scale(1375).toFixed()); // 1
```

You can try it yourself at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bngtlrs/QMQrk/).

Comment: Any idea how this could be accomplished in d3 v4 ?

Comment: This is working for me in d3 v4 to get a fixed point with SI prefix:
`value = 238489000; console.log(d3.formatPrefix('.1f', value)(value));` **// 238.5**

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change your

```
d3.format('.1s');
```

by

```
d3.format('.3s');
```

```js
console.log(d3.format(".3s")(12600000));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```